# By chance does this have a radical form or is it just a irrational decimal?

Tags: trigonometry

I am wondering if this is just a non-ending decimal or is it possible to write it as a radical form? So far I found non-ending decimals.
This is the equation: $$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac45\right)$$

Comment: If $\cos{\theta}=4/5$, then $e^{i\theta}$ is an algebraic number. By the Lindemann theorem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann–Weierstrass_theorem), $\theta$ is transcendental. Using the rational root theorem and the Shebychev polynomials, you can also see that $\theta/\pi$ is irrational as well.

Comment: No, it is not. See Niven's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem